I want to generate an edit URL only for specific form responses using an app script
This is my demo sheet and form to help you understand my problem. I have written an app script on the sheet to generate the URL. Actually, I am working on a different sheet on which thousands of records are present. To generate the URL link of the responses, the script is taking a very long time, and due to this, we are not able to work properly. 
That's why I want the script that generates the URLs of specific responses only, not all. Please help, guys!
Form:- https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Qw6z_ZoCF7iFsseIKXXfhU5k0n7hT5-HGN_049ApagY/edit
enter image description here
enter image description here
Sheet:- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KhTQk9i4PHEeNECY3BdbM04gAOKLGboUe8b2ZHng3po/edit#gid=836881824
enter image description here
I want the script that generates the URLs of specific responses only, not all. Please help, guys!

copy the code into the question itself

"URLs of specific responses only" What are the criteria for selecting these responses?


format code


The app script code below will get the Edit Form URLs only for the selected rows on the spreadsheet.  Be sure that the rows selected are consecutive and then run the function selectedRows().  I added the script to the Apps Script Editor as well for testing. It would probably help to add this function in a Custom Menu using the onOpen() function as well.
 function selectedRows() {
  var startingRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var rowCount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getNumRows();
  
  
  var form = FormApp.openById('1Qw6z_ZoCF7iFsseIKXXfhU5k0n7hT5-HGN_049ApagY');
    //enter form ID here

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test1');

    //Change the sheet name as appropriate
  var dataRaw = sheet.getRange(startingRow,1,rowCount).getValues()
  dataRaw = dataRaw.flat();
  var data = [];

  //Set milliseconds for each timestamp and push to new array data
  for (var y = 0; y < dataRaw.length; y++){
    data.push(dataRaw[y].setMilliseconds(0));
  }
  Logger.log(data)


  var urlCol = 4; // column number where URL's should be populated; A = 1, B = 2 etc
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var urls = [];

  
  //Loop through each time stamp in data and check it against all timestamps in response array.  If it matches push the edit URL to the urls array
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   
    for (var x = 0; x < responses.length; x++){
      if(responses[x].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0) == data[i]){
      urls.push([responses[x].getEditResponseUrl()]);
    
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(urls)
  //Set the edit URLs on the spreadsheet
  sheet.getRange(startingRow,urlCol,dataRaw.length).setValues(urls);
}


I have run this script, but it shows this error: TypeError: dataRaw[y]. setMilliseconds is not a function.
selectedRows  @ Code.gs:41

It is likely that you selected rows on Sheet1 (which I just deleted) instead of Test1.  Please select consecutive rows on Test1 and try again.
